# How to add suctom column based on some condition in query

Tags: php, mysql

I have database of ship hom whicn I wand to select data from my ship table with a custom column based on some value:

```
shipid    shipname   capacity   hullnum  
5476      Alin       2540000    475
7655      star       3340000
```

I have to check if any number exist under hull num then it's  hullbuilder else shipbuilder (hard coaded texts).

I am new to mysql. please help me how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with simple `if /else` in select clause.

like below:

```
SELECT shipid,shipname,capacity,
    if(hullnum is not NULL OR hulnum!='','hullbuilder','shipbilder') as builder
  FROM ship
```

Comment: I'm thinking OP wants those columns selected, not hard-coded text.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a `CASE` statement as well:

```
SELECT shipid, shipname, capacity,
  CASE WHEN COALESCE(hullnum, '') != ''
      THEN 'hullbuilder'
      ELSE 'shipbuilder'
   END as builder
  FROM ship
```